# IOS UIButton not responding to touch, takes multiple presses, UIScreenEdge Gesture interference?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I've got a series of modal views that I present, each of which has a top title toolbar and UIBarButtonItem in the upper right with an "X" image that allows the user to click on it to dismiss the view.

The problem I'm having is that **frequently these buttons are not responding to the touch**, and seem to take 5-10 taps before they do their action. I even increased the button's image size to make the area bigger, but no help.  In the Simulator however, with the click of the mouse pointer, they seem to work instantly without issue.

One thing I noticed is that the main view seems to have a UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer on it that I haven't added.  I think it is for the Iphone notification center handle which can be pulled down from the top.  There is one on the bottom too.  Are these interfering with my buttons?  Those handles always respond to a slight drag down.

I did a test where I put the button in the middle of the screen, and it works instantly every time.  The top and bottom are obvious places for toolbars and buttons though, it seems odd that the edge gesture recognizer would cause this conflict and not make everyone mad.

```
// The button, added as part of a standard toolbar on very top of screen
UIButton *closeButtonImage = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[closeButtonImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[closeButtonImage setFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 35, 9, 26, 26)];
[closeButtonImage addTarget:self action:@selector(closeClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIBarButtonItem *closeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:closeButtonImage];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
[closeButtonImage setFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 35, 9, 26, 26)];
```

Try this:

```
[closeButtonImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 26)];
```

Reason: You are putting a button *inside a UIBarButtonItem*. This is somewhat odd, because a bar button item itself *is* a kind of button, but there is nothing wrong with it. However, it is up to the bar button item where to place its content. If you put the button outside the bounds of the containing bar button item, it becomes untappable.

Truly, though, my real suggestion is not to do what you're doing. Just give the UIBarButtonItem itself the `close.png` image as its image, and set the action on the bar button item itself. It is a button already.

Comment: Great catch!  This seems to have been the problem, not the gesture at all.  They respond well now. This clearly makes perfect sense, since the frame rect origin is relative to its parent, the UIBarButtonItem.  Must have got left in when I tried to just add the UIButton to the toolbar, which never works of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using others types for  "`forControlEvents:`" such as `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.